# How to get registered FingerPrint count in android phone

Tags: android, android-biometric

I want to reset fingerprint authentication in my application, if any fingerprint added/removed. I have used `setUserAuthenticationRequired(true)` & `setInvalidatedByBiometricEnrollment(true)` properties for this, but I am getting KeyPermanentlyInvalidatedException only if any new fingerprint added or all fingerprints are removed from phone. Hence, I need a count of registered fingerprint in phone. So that any of fingerprint gets deleted, I will reset the authentication in my app. How to get that count? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks !!

Comment: If you're that worried about unauthorized users, why not require the user to authenticate more frequently (like any time they take an action that requires an authorized user, or any time they launch an Activity) instead?  Either of those is actually more secure.